# How to write Product Id in registry in wix

Tags: wix

My requirement is blow. 
I need to write the Product Id in registry while install the setup. 
I have the below code for Product Id.

```xml
<Product Id="{CEEE7807-F6D7-43F6-A206-110B9E25AC9C}" 
         Name="Sample installer" 
         UpgradeCode="{BFBD4770-8C5D-4A53-BA07-EF52401F0CB4}" 
         Language="1033" 
         Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" 
         Manufacturer="My company.">
```

I have below code for write Registry. I want to pass the product Id value here.

```xml
<Component Id="registry_values" Guid="{11FB6C4C-3C90-4F46-B0D2-BB95150F60E6}">
    <RegistryValue 
         KeyPath="yes" 
         Root="HKCU" 
         Key="Software\MyProduct\Myfolder\SampleFolder\Product" 
         Value="[Product Id]" 
         Type="string" />
</Component>
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You should probably set the Product Id to `*` so that it is different for each generated installer. You only need a fixed product id if you want to support patching scenarios with `.msp` files (i.e. "minor updates").

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Somewhat confusingly, the `Id` attribute of the WIX [Product](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_product.htm) element maps to the Windows Installer `ProductCode` property.

```xml
<Component Id="registry_values" Guid="{11FB6C4C-3C90-4F46-B0D2-BB95150F60E6}">
    <RegistryValue 
         KeyPath="yes" 
         Root="HKCU" 
         Key="Software\MyProduct\Myfolder\SampleFolder\Product" 
         Value="[ProductCode]" 
         Type="string" />
</Component>
```

Comment: @Vinoth, if it is, accept the answer - the author will appreciate this ;)